# Code::Blocks started delaying the console output

Tags: performance, compilation, delay, codeblocks

First of all I'd like to say hello to the community, I'm quite new to programming and this community overall, and I'm just learning programming cause I find it interesting. Lately, I've stumbled upon an issue.

This hasn't happened before and I did not change a single setting in Code::Blocks. Whenever I compile and run (F9), the console text shows up only after about 2-3 seconds. This delay is really annoying and I'm unsure what could be the cause. It doesn't matter how long the code is or what I'm compiling and running, as this happens equally from a simple Hello World! program to something of 80 lines. This is not a very big issue but it is quite irritating and I'd like to know if this has happened to others or if I can follow some suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, nevermind. This issue was due to my antivirus for some reason (Using Panda Antivirus). Whenever I stop it, the problem doesn't happen for some reason. I'll need to look into this.